# Is there any way to connect external graphics cards to the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: power, linux, gpu

I would like to connect graphics cards to my Raspberry Pi, for example an RX 580.

I can also buy an external power supply unit to supply it with power.

So is it somehow possible that the Raspberry Pi works under Linux / Windows with this or a similar graphics card?

Comment: https://youtu.be/MxcafwjWw24. But _why?_

Answer (score 1):

Look at the specs of the graphics card and the Raspberry Pi.

If one of the inputs to the graphics card matches one of the outputs from the Raspberry Pi it will work.  It might need considerable software effort on your part to make it usable.

If there is no match it will not work.

Comment: I am aware that if the graphics card has a connection that fits on the rasperri then it works.  But what the real problem is.  I don't know anything about rasperri.  I really don't know anything.  I just don't know about it.  That's why I asked a question whether the rx 580 works on the Rasperri

Comment: So why don't you look at the specs rather than ask here?  The information is not secret.

Comment: The only thing I found is about the USB port.  I am trying to connect the eGPU via USB.  I hope the Rasberry pi 4 can handle it without any problems.  thanks for your answers